# Redirecting HTTPS to HTTP via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I'm using a WordPress with its default .htaccess and I need to redirect all urls starting with https:// to http://. My server is using the same folder for http and https protocols...
this is my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule> 
# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

It works fine for https://www.domain.com/ (redirects to http://www.domain.com/) but it doesn't work with https://www.domain.com/subpages/ (it also redirects to http://www.domain.com/).

Do you see any problem in .htaccess please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Change the order of the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise the WordPress rule will catch all request that’s URL path is not empty (i.e. not just `/`).