# Redirect old https to http via htaccess within wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, https

I've just rebuilt an old website with wordpress for a client. The old website had all its pages as https://

I want to redirect all those https pages to http
The old pages were in format like this: https://example.com/index.php?stm_a=23&m=279&r=98ab55fe446d960a&rid=98ab55fe446d960a and I have to redirect those to new permalink structure like:
/about/
/contact/
etc

I tried redirecting all traffic from https to http using the [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717799/redirecting-https-to-http-via-htaccess) to no avail

My current htaccess file reads:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Appreciate any help I can get.
Kind regards,
Mihai

Answer (score 0):

After `RewriteEngine On`, try adding the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ravij!

Now when i try to access the index of the site in https:// I get redirected to a default page /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi which says something like:"If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the web site owner: etc"

Comment: https (root) should redirect to http (root).
https subpages should redirect to http subpages.