# htaccess to rewrite all HTTPS requests to HTTP version

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I'm trying to disable HTTPS on domain names that do not have SSL certificates, I am using this code but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. My website is running Wordpress and the wordpress htaccess is working fine, but the HTTPS bit seems to be nothing. This is the code I am using with wordpress' htaccess:

I'm now using the code from the 'possible duplicate' above and it's not working for me:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting HTTPS to HTTP via .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717799/redirecting-https-to-http-via-htaccess)

Comment: I just tried that solution but it didn't seem to make a change to the http/https functionality at all; the domain is http://emeraldcoastyoungmarines.com/ the htaccess from that link is running on it now

Answer (score 1):

You're using capture group # 1 i.e. `$1` without using capturing a group using square brackets.

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My htaccess contains your code (along with 'RewriteEngine on') but it still doesn't seem to be redirecting; if I go to https:// it still loads, it doesn't force it to http://

Comment: What is your full URL that you tested?

Comment: http://emeraldcoastyoungmarines.com it is running the code above (in the question) now, but still not working. :(

Comment: `http://emeraldcoastyoungmarines.com/` and `https://emeraldcoastyoungmarines.com/` are showing 2 totally different pages. Most likely you have 2 different DOCUMENT_ROOT setup in your VirtuaHost entries. If that's indeed the case then `https://www.emeraldcoastyoungmarines.com/` isn't even executing this rule.

Comment: Turn on rewrite rule logging at level 9 - it will tell you exactly what is going on. Great way to debug... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215316/how-do-i-troubleshoot-why-my-rewrite-rules-arent-being-applied-by-apache

Comment: @anubhava thank you, I contacted my host (Host Gator) based on your question regarding the Virtual Host entries and after 2 hours with them on support, they confirmed it was a problem they created when they installed an SSL certificate improperly. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. That is great to know. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

There was a misconfiguration on the server that was preventing the rewrite rules from functioning. I contacted Host Gator and they confirmed they had installed an SSL certificate improperly which was causing the problems.

Thank you all for your help; I greatly appreciate it.

Below is the email from HostGator for archival purposes of this question.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Host Gator, I will be more than happy to
>   assist you with this.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this has caused.
>
> It appears your SSL was installed incorrectly, we have updated your IP
>   for the SSL and you should have no other issue with it.
>
> If you have any other questions please let us know.
>
> Regards, 
>   Elizabeth R. 
>   HostGator.com LLC

Answer (score 0):

**Always use https for secure connections

Replace 'www.example.com' with your domain name
(as it appears on your SSL certificate**)

**Put this code inside .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Reference](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/ssl-setup-use/i-have-purchased-a-ssl-from-you-now-how-do-i-use-it)